# Incorporate ocean crossing cost to mobility model in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, cost-path, movement-data, least-cost, ocean

When making a cost distance map in ArcGIS Pro, how does one make the value of oceans high, and as a result harder to cross than the land?

I am making a map of movement from sites in Europe such as Jersey, and Lille, and want to have the cost distance fan out from the sites which I've done. However, it ignores oceans as being impossible to cross by foot, just continuing to fan out, how can I make it so that the ocean is impossible to cross. Basically, how do I give just certain areas a much higher cost value?

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you could model boat/ferry traffic between ports as having no walking cost and oceans as impassable.

Comment: I'm using modern day data as a proxy for centuries ago, well before ferries and even boats and don't have access to ferry routes, etc. How would I give an area 'no walking cost'?

Comment: Barriers are infinite cost.

Comment: Don't know if I am giving you a red herring but setting pixels to NODATA excludes them from such analysis? If that's what you want?  There is the SetNull tool to recode if necessary.